# How can I change the color inside a canvas element according to some data?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, canvas, react-redux

I have a canvas element. I want the color inside it to change according to some data? Can someone help me with that?

```js
import React from 'react';

class Canvas extends React.Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        this.updateCanvas();
    }
    updateCanvas() {
      const ctx = this.refs.canvas.getContext('2d');
      var grd=ctx.createLinearGradient(50,0,40,0);
      grd.addColorStop(0,"#A52A2A");
      grd.addColorStop(1/4,"#00597d");
      ctx.fillStyle = grd;
      ctx.fillRect(0,0, 100, 100);
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <canvas ref="canvas" width={this.props.width} height={this.props.height}/>
        );
    }
}

export default Canvas;
```

Comment: More explanation is needed !

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick example of changing the data based on the React state.  This should give the basics needed for changing the color in other ways. (You could replace the select tags with inputs, or use fetch to get some data from a server.)

```
    class Canvas extends React.Component {
    // The constructor is used to set default values for your Colors (#A52A2A, #00597d).
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            colorOne: "#A52A2A",
            colorTwo: "#00597d"
        };
        this.updateComponent = this.updateComponent.bind(this);
      }
    // Update the canvas on componentDidMount as the canvas is not present before mounting
      componentDidMount() {
        this.updateCanvas();
      }
    // Update the canvas on any changes to the React state.
      componentDidUpdate() {
        this.updateCanvas();
      }
    // Set new values for the React state based on the option selected.
      updateComponent(event) {
        this.setState({
            [event.target.name]: event.target.value
        });
      }   
    // Update the canvas.
      updateCanvas() {
        const ctx = this.refs.canvas.getContext('2d');
        var grd=ctx.createLinearGradient(50,0,40,0);
        grd.addColorStop(0,this.state.colorOne);
        grd.addColorStop(1/4,this.state.colorTwo);
        ctx.fillStyle = grd;
        ctx.fillRect(0,0, 100, 100);
      }
    // render the canvas and a way for the user to change the canvas color. 
      render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <canvas ref="canvas" width={this.props.width} height={this.props.height}/>
                <select type="select" onChange={this.updateComponent} name="colorOne">
                    <option value="#A52A2A">Original</option>
                    <option value="#ff0000">Red</option>
                    <option value="#bfff00">Green</option></select>
                <select type="select" onChange={this.updateComponent} name="colorTwo">
                    <option value="#00597d">Original</option>
                    <option value="#ff0000">Red</option>
                    <option value="#bfff00">Green</option></select>
            </div>
        );
      } 
  } export default Canvas;
```